# Как мне создать метод transfer(), который удаляет игрока из одной команды и назначает игрока в другую команду?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Указываем id игрока (которого хотим купить) и id команды (куда хотим вставить игрока). У игрока уже есть команда. Нам нужно сначала удалить его из команды, а затем вставить в другую команду. Что-то вроде этого кода). Spring Boot.

```
public void  buyPlayer(PlayerDTO playerDTO, TeamDTO teamDTO) {
        Team team2 = teamService.getOne(teamDTO.getId());
        Player player2 =  map(playerDTO);
        playerRepository.deleteById(playerDTO.getId());
        long cost = playerDTO.getFinalCost();
        long budget = teamDTO.getBudget() + cost;
        teamDTO.setBudget(budget);
        player2.setTeam(team2);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Удаление игрока при помощи `playerRepository.deleteById(playerDTO.getId());` явно некорректно.

В сущности `Team` имеет смысл хранить список игроков `List<Player>`, для которого следует реализовать пару методов `addPlayer / removePlayer`.  Тогда метод `transfer` может выглядеть так:

```java
public void transfer(PlayerDTO playerDTO, TeamDTO teamDTO,) {
    Player player = map(playerDTO);
    Team oldTeam = player.getTeam();
    Team newTeam = teamService.getOne(teamDTO.getId());

    oldTeam.removePlayer(player);
    // старая команда получает деньги за переход, бюджет увеличивается
    oldTeam.setBudget(oldTeam.getBudget() + playerDTO.getFinalCost());

    newTeam.addPlayer(player);
    // новая команда платит деньги за переход, бюджет уменьшается
    newTeam.setBudget(newTeam.getBudget() - playerDTO.getFinalCost());
    // player.setTeam(newTeam);

    // суммарная стоимость игроков обеих команд должна пересчитаться после сохранения
    teamService.save(oldTeam);
    teamService.save(newTeam);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо)
Но у меня появляется ошибка.
Вот здесь:
    teamService.save(oldTeam);
    teamService.save(newTeam);
Вот мой метод create:
Team create(TeamDTO teamDTO);